# Flask-SQLAlchemy `with Session.begin() as sess` issue

Tags: flask-sqlalchemy

I am using the Flask-SQLAlchemy construct `with Session.begin() as sess:` for session management. I have a function that creates a new object in a table and updates an existing object.

When the `with Session.begin` block ends, the new object is present in the database, but the modified object is showing as unmodified.

I've tried just about everything except switching the way the Session is managed and used.

Comment: So I just modified a second attribute (datetime column) and the modified datetime DOES show up in the database. The column that isn't showing up in the database is a boolean.